# D Cell Batteries Amperage

Tags: batteries

I have a battery powered device that accepts 4 x D cell batteries, it also has a 6V DC input slot to run off a charger/mains. There is no mention on the device/manufacturers website of the amperage for the charger/mains.

What sort of amperage would 4 x D cell batteries produce?

Comment: What is the device?

Comment: read the D cell datasheet ... it should be available on the manufacturer's website

Comment: @KevinWhite It's a telescope part. Celestron dual-axis motor drive for CG-4 mounts #93522.

Comment: Chinese "sooper heavy dooty" batteries are cheap and produce a low maximum current for a short duration.

Answer (score 1):

D-cells can provide such a wide amperage range (the more the amps, the shorter the run-time) that it's not useful as a guide for sizing an AC adapter.

The equipment should state the amps required.  Possibly on the inlet on the device, but definitely on the AC adapter which they sell for the purpose of feeding that inlet.  You don't need to buy the adapter, just find a high enough resolution picture where the amps or watts figure can be read.  Make sure to read the spec on the DC side.  If you read the AC side watts by mistake, they will be a bit higher, and that won't really hurt your project - a few extra watts on the supply never hurts.  However, if you read the AC side amps, it will understate amps by a factor of 10 or 20, and that would lead you to get much too small an adapter!

Comment: "Any amperage you want, but the more the amps, the shorter the run-time."  Not really -- I'm not sure what a shorted alkaline D-cell will provide, but I'm almost certain it's less than ten amps.  If you can find a true D-sized NiMH or NiCd (not just a C-cell inside) then it would deliver considerably more.

Comment: @Tim OK, edited.

Comment: @TimWescott You don't really want to short NiCd...  They were responsible for most recycling bin fires in medieval times.

Comment: @user107063 yes -- my wording was bad.  I flew electric model airplanes back in the NiCd days -- we'd get at least 10A out of a 2/3 sub-C cell at wide open throttle, without needing an actual short circuit to be present.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Unfortunately already tried to find any image possible but they don't even sell an adapter for it, it seems. It is a pretty out dated device. If I was able to find one would of just gone ahead and got a 3rd party one based on the rating.

Answer (score 0):

Good alkaline D cells can deliver a few amps for a little while*.  You're probably better off estimating the drain of the device (which is almost certainly less) than going from what a D cell could do when stressed.

---

* I use them as model airplane glow plug ignitors.  In typical usage, a pair of D-cells in parallel will deliver 500 to 1000 starts before you need to chuck them and build a new pack.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere between 8 to 18 Ah, for non-rechargeables. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_battery

Comment: That's capacity. Not amount of current.